# Else statement won't work in for loop

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a function here that is not working as I hoped it would. After a bit of testing, I discovered that it is not running the "else if" statement.
Here is the code:

```
getWeights : function() {
    weights = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < hiddenLayer.length; i++) {
        weights[i] = {};
        for (var j = 0; j < Object.keys(hiddenLayer[i]).length * 3; j++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                for (var t = 0; t < input.length; t++) {
                    weights[i]["weightsSet" + j] = 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                weightCalc = Object.keys(hiddenLayer[i - 1]).length;
                for (var u = 0; u < Object.keys(hiddenLayer[i]).length * weightCalc; u++) {
                    weights[i]["weightsSet" + j] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Please help me find out why it won't work.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT
Removed comment

EDIT 2
I figured out the problem. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Can you include an example of what `hiddenLayer` would be.

Comment: Well hidden layer only has no properties u guess

Comment: It would help if we know what hiddenLayer contains.  console.log(hiddenLayer) before the first loop to see what we have.

Comment: Since your loop `i` is going from 0 to `hiddenLayer.length`, it can never be less than zero. So, there is no sense in this `else if`.

Comment: @JosephGarrone [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)??? 100% valid usage.

Comment: I agree with @YeldarKurmangaliyev it should just be an `else`, not `else if`

Comment: @JosephGarrone "Object" is not a variable and "hiddenLayer" is just an array with objects in it.

Comment: @Iceclaw12 can you `console.log(hiddenlayer)` as per @will

Comment: @epascarello Wasn't saying incorrect usage, just never seen it before. I should have checked to see if it existed.

Comment: I don't know what the intent of this code is, but my guess is you're not getting the results you expect because you're inspecting the outer loop index inside of your inner loop. I would suspect you'd want to put your if/else logic that inspects the value of `i` outside of your inner loop.

Comment: in the console hiddenLayer comes up as: [Objectneuron0Sum: nullneuron1Sum: nullneuron2Sum: null, Objectneuron0Sum: nullneuron1Sum: nullneuron2Sum: NaN]

Comment: and changing else if to else doesn't work

Comment: update your question with else and remove  else becuase it is obvious  when i == 0 condition is false then it will come inside else and that means i > 0 then no need to use else if

Comment: @BrianDriscoll I get even worse results when I put it outside the inner loop

Comment: I also notice one of your inner loops references a variable named input that is not defined inside this function. Can you provide context for that variable?

Comment: Debug your code by stepping through it in a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying the function as follows and then debug to see what is happening:

```
getWeights : function() {
    weights = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < hiddenLayer.length; i++) {

        weights[i] = {};
        var limit = input.length;

        if (i > 0) {
            var weightCalc = Object.keys(hiddenLayer[i - 1]).length;
            limit = Object.keys(hiddenLayer[i]).length * weightCalc;
        } 

        for (var j = 0; j < Object.keys(hiddenLayer[i]).length * 3; j++) {
            for (var t = 0; t < limit; t++) {
                    weights[i]["weightsSet" + j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For any further help you would need to add data related to this code, and expected output in your question.

Answer (score -2):

Check 2nd or 3rd for loop may be its running for infinitive number of times

Comment: they aren't looping infinitely